# Why do this occurs "Could not load file or assembly.." in C# class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm newbie to .net projects. Although I was able to code in c# & use it's frameworks, Some times I face exceptions which I really didn't get any proper resource/suggestion to modify or rectify them. Hope I would get clear this time.

The exception which I faced is as follows :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm really confused with such type of exceptions. What's the reason for those & how we needs to cross check to clear those ?
Here is what I did install: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation" from nuget console with version 2.2.0.

My installed packages list image :
[image: Image Reference of installed packages]

Comment: You still need to add a reference to it.  Under references in the project/solution, you need to add the reference to it.

Comment: There is a known issue about the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation", maybe this link can help https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/401

Comment: @Brad It's a dotnet core project. So there wont be reference. When I install directly it falls in packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this type of error is a result of your output folder.  Take a look at where your binary outputs were placed.  Inside of that folder (usually your .exe or .dll output, not sure what kind of .NET project you're writing), you should also have all of your dependency dlls.  In this case, the dll related to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation is missing.  So when you go to run your executable, it complains "Could not load file or assembly KeyDerivation" because it couldn't find it.

To resolve this issue, double check your project's references and that there are no issues with the Microsoft.AspNetcore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation reference (what I mean is, make sure there are no yellow exclamations or other icons showing up next to this reference in your Solution Explorer).  If you have any issues, remove the reference, then add the nuget package again.

Comment: I had posted the image of dependencies. There is no such yellow exclamations icon after that package.